# How can I verify webBrowser success load XML file with XSL style sheet

Tags: c#, xml, webbrowser-control, xls

I build app that parsing xml files into datagridview and I have another panel contain webbrowser to show the xml file. The webBrowser show the xml files with style (from XSL and CSS files).
I parsing the xml files from path that given by the user.

Now, I want to know if the webBrowser success to load the xml file (if the style files really exist) or not (the style files doesn't exist).

- I not using *File.Exist* because the really question is a little more complex (I simplified the question)

I try this:

```
    void showXMLInWebBrowser(int rowIndex)
    {
        string XMLPath = "";

        XMLPath = set.XMLPath + "\\";
        XMLPath += dg_xml.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        XMLPath += "\\" + dg_xml.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString();

        Uri path = new Uri(XMLPath);
        wb_XML.Url = path;

        // I try this - but it's not show any message
        if (wb_XML.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) MessageBox.Show("Complete");
    }
```

This is "failed-load" capture:

[image]

Comment: How about using xml parser to validate file before opening by webbrowser

Comment: The problem is not in the xml file, but in the style files that miss

Comment: check "Validation Against XML Schema (XSD) with the XmlValidatingReader" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thydszwy.aspx

Comment: @volody: thank you. I just now see your answer... but I really will read this!